# Center custom HTML Object

Tags: html

I got a custom HTML-object and every way I tried to center the class, it failed. Does anybody have an idea? Kind regards.

I tried . Other objects ere centered, only this one wasn't. I tried margin: 0px auto. I tried . My custom object keeps left-aligned. I think there could be an attribute

```css
.switch-mode {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-mode input {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-mode label {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-mode label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-mode input:checked+label {
  background-color: #C23434;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-mode label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-mode label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="switch-mode">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-open" name="mode" />
    <label for="radio-open">OPEN</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-auto" name="mode" />
    <label for="radio-auto">AUTO</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-close" name="mode" />
    <label for="radio-close">CLOSE</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this help: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 3):

Your container is what needs to be centered, not the items within it. The addition is `justify-content: center;` within the `.switch-mode` class.

```css
.switch-mode {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
}

.switch-mode input {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-mode label {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-mode label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-mode input:checked+label {
  background-color: #C23434;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-mode label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-mode label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="switch-mode">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-open" name="mode" />
    <label for="radio-open">OPEN</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-auto" name="mode" />
    <label for="radio-auto">AUTO</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-close" name="mode" />
    <label for="radio-close">CLOSE</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `justify-content: center;` seems to be the answer here :)

Answer (score 2):

On `.switch-mode`, you have used `flex` layout. So add `justify-content: center` on `.switch-mode` class and it will be aligned on center position.

```css
.switch-mode {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
}

.switch-mode input {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-mode label {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-mode label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-mode input:checked+label {
  background-color: #C23434;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-mode label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-mode label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="switch-mode">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-open" name="mode" />
    <label for="radio-open">OPEN</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-auto" name="mode" />
    <label for="radio-auto">AUTO</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-close" name="mode" />
    <label for="radio-close">CLOSE</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```